# glutkeyboardfunc x,y parameters

Tags: keyboard, glut

On GLUT glutkeyboardfunc it returns 3 values I understand the char parameter but don't understand the other 2 are. Want do these parameters mean?

Comment: I solve it right after I asked it. It seems to be mouse x,y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional params are the x and y callback parameters indicate the mouse location in window relative coordinates when the key was pressed